# How can I setup a Bluetooth device to serve web pages to a BT client via TCP/HTTP?

Tags: bluetooth, tcp

I'm thinking of making a linux-based Blueooth enabled device, which allows an external client (e.g. a laptop) to connect to it via TCP over Bluetooth and retrive web pages which allow it to interact with the device without having to install additional client software. Is this a crazy thing to try to do? What BT services should I be trying to support in the device to make BT TCP connection and networking as simple to setup as possible?

Comment: This tuturial sounds really promising: https://neonexxa.medium.com/how-to-serve-localhost-in-rapsbery-pi-thru-bluetooth-8e2e0d74da74 I will give it a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out[`BNEP/PAN`](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BNEP.aspx). It has good support by most OS:es and gives you virtual network interfaces on the devices and you can run TCP as usual without handling all the B. 
The [documentation (PDF)](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=6552) is quite thorough.

Comment: This link explains why: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=93455