# Connect to web server on Windows over bluetooth using iPhone

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, bluetooth, webserver, iphone

For web development, I currently setup a web server to listen on my LAN interface IP address on Windows, and I can connect to the web server using any device on my LAN.  Instead of using the LAN interface, I want to do the same thing over Bluetooth.  That is, I would get an IP address for the Bluetooth interface on my Windows machine, have the web server listen on the Bluetooth IP address, and then connect to the web server from my iPhone using the iPhone's Bluetooth interface.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [Serving a local website via bluetooth to a cellphone without using the internet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10502645)

Comment: [How can I setup a Bluetooth device to serve web pages to a BT client via TCP/HTTP?](http://superuser.com/q/399279)

Comment: Thanks, but those links don't have anything concrete, especially for Windows.  The second link is for a protocol specification.